# Trying to use if function in Kotlin class

Tags: function, class, kotlin, if-statement

I don´t know why it doesn´t work..
I cant use if or when functions in class or in the "playerPosition" function..

```
class Player(val name:String, val nachname: String, val nr:Int) {
    var position = mutableListOf<Int>(0,1,2,3)
    var playerPosi = Int


    fun playerPosition(){

      if(playerPosi < 3 ){

      }
    }

}
```

And the next question is, how can I use a function from a class in the main func.?
Maybe like this

```
class Player(val name:String, val nachname: String, val nr:Int, var playerPosi : Int) {
    var position = mutableListOf<Int>(0,1,2,3)



    fun playerPosition(){

      if(playerPosi > 3 ){
          println("Diese Position gibt es nicht")

      }
    }



   }
```

**MAIN FUNCTION**

```
fun main(){
    val team2 = mutableListOf<Player>()
    team2.add(Player("Berkan", "Kutlu", 10,4))
    val spieler = Player("Wesley","Sneijder",10,4)


    playerPosition()

    println("${team2.first().playerPosi}")



    }
```

**notice**
Im trying to set the max Int from playerPosi to 3. Because of Offense, Middfield and Defense and Keeper
If Ive the numbers from 0 to 3 I will try to identify 0 as Keeper 1 as Defense and so on.

Thanks for you patience with me :D

Comment: I can't help but notice that this is your second question in which it seems that you just lack the basics of the language syntax. Have you looked at [the official Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html)? It's full of resources that should help you learn the basics, take a look at [Basic Syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html), [Kotlin by example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/overview) and [Koans](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/overview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First question

The problem here is not the if keyword, it's because the property playerPosi is wrong.

Instead of writing :

```kotlin
var playerPosi = Int
```

you need to write :

```kotlin
var playerPosi: Int
```

Why ?

In kotlin, you have two way to declare a variable / property :

- var : mutable variable / property, you can change it's value
- val : read-only variable (check Tenfour04 response)

After the var / val keyword you give it a name

And after that you have three choices :

- Directly give a value and kotlin will infer the type

```kotlin
var playerPosi = 1
```

- Give it a type and initialize it latter

```kotlin
var playerPosi: Int
```

- Give it a type and initialize it

```kotlin
var playerPosi: Int = 1
```

## Second Question

If you want to call a method of an object (here it's Player), you need to :

- Instantiate it
- Get the reference
- Call the method from the reference

So, if we take your sample :

```kotlin
    val team2 = mutableListOf<Player>()
    team2.add(Player("Berkan", "Kutlu", 10,4))
    val spieler = Player("Wesley","Sneijder",10,4) // Instantiate + take the reference on spieler variable.


    speiler.playerPosition() // here you call the playerPosition method with the speiler variable

    println("${team2.first().playerPosi}")
```

Comment: `val` (for a property) is not necessarily immutable. It’s read-only. If you give it a custom getter, it can produce different values. Also, `playerPosi` is a property, not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing from `var playerPosi = Int` to `var playerPosi: Int`, with `:` instead of `=`. If you want to define the data type, you should use `:`; `=` is used to assign value.

To use the function on object you have previously created, you should first specify the object you want the function to be called into, then a dot, and then the function's name. Like this:

```
fun main(){
    val spieler = Player("Wesley","Sneijder",10,4)
    spieler.playerPosition()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case: `var playerPosi = Int` is wrong syntax. Declaration should be `var playerPosi: Int`.

In the second case: if `player` is object of class `Player`, the you can do `player.playerPosi`.

`main()` function seems to be written for variant #2, where `playerPosi` is also constructor parameter.